# Recommendations for missing primary key

Tags: sql-server, database-design, primary-key

I’m thinking about creating a database using an excel file from a hospital equipment inventory a while ago. the main there is a sample from the many tables in the attached image. the columns are:

- code - given by the hospital and found in a tag pasted on the equipment
- location - where the equipment was found at the time the inventory was taken (won’t be using it)
- name - name of the equipment
- brand - brand of the equipment
- model - model of the equipment
- serial number - found on the equipment
- does it work? - this was done to keep track of which ones had to receive maintenance
- observations - text space to specify missing pieces, visible damage, etc

I'm planing to use SQL Server to do this project.

So my question is: I'm thinking of using the code as primary key, given every device has its own. Thing is, some of the devices are really old and the painting, tags and other identifiers have come off or even the personnel takes them off (don't ask me why) so if I can’t generate a primary key in the same way as they did how can I adjust my PK to fit the pattern? (many devices are missing the code so taking them out is not an option). I thought of generating a new PK and leaving the code as another column but I don’t know if that is a good practice.

Any of you guys have any recommendations?

Thank you for reading.

[table sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G7hN.png)

Comment: You need to think "business key", a property or set of properties that you would use in real life to identify a thing, and "technical key", an identifier used to facilitate storage and references.

Comment: Opinion based, but we are always using separate identity column for PK. Maybe for your case codes are unique and do never change; generally this is not granted.

Comment: I don't understand at all why this request has been closed. I think the business case is well described (and we can always ask questions, if we want more information) and the question is: would the tag code be appropriate for a primary key or not? I consider this a very good question. (And saying that we can always add a surrogate key does not answer this in the least. Of course we can, but how to reflect the business case in the database?) I am voting to have this request reopened.

Comment: In other words: The question whether the tag code could be the primary key or not is not opinion-based at all. There has been decribed a real-world scenario here and wondering what would be the appropriate business key is the path to get to a proper database for the described scenario. I am often surprised to hear people say: "Let's introduce a surrogate key, then we don't have to think about this further". This is not how to build a good database. We can use surrogate keys alright, but we must still think about how to deal with the real-world keys in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The code uniquely identifies an equipment. So, yes, this is the perfect primary key.

Then there is this issue that codes are sometimes removed from equipment or no longer readable for some reason. What I'd do in this case is: Look up the equipment in the table (by name, brand, etc.). Three possibilities:

1. There is exactly one piece of equipment matching. Then use this code and tag the equipment with it again.
2. There is more than one equipment matching. Use a new code and tag the equipment with it. Make a remark in the record that this is an interims code for the time until the real code is found. At the time of stocktaking there will be one of the origimal matching equipments missing (because its original code has been lost). We can then adjust the data (i.e. keep one of the two rows and logically or physically delete the other, change remarks, re-tag the equipment, whatever - you decide how you want this to be documented in your table).
3. There is no matching row in the table. Mysterious. Decide what to do in this case.